# multiple user's information given facebook ids

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

I need to get multiple users off of facebook in one call, sending the ids of the desired users, i won't know how many users i need to get each time, as it is dynamic.
Have searched multiple places, and managed to find a few solutions however none that seem quite viable or efficient.

One is a foreach, using the facebook c# sdk get method... really not efficient.
The closest i have managed to come is with the following, where s would be a string of comma delimited ids:

```
        var requestString = string.Format("https://graph.facebook.com?ids={0}", s);
        var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(requestString);
        request.ContentType = "GET";
        try
        {
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            if (response != null)
            {
                if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
                    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
                    {
                        var html = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    }
                }
                response.Close();
            }
        }
        catch { }
```

This returns what i need in some horrible html format.

Is there a better way to do this, either using batch requests, or using a simple get?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go with [batch requests](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api/batch/) over the comma-delimited ids. At least then you are shown a pre-defined json structure that they will send you.